# Why was my question closed as "too localized"?

Tags: support

Why was my question closed as too localized?

I asked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98339/how-do-i-ensure-my-images-graphics-are-embedded-in-the-output-document) and it was closed as too localized.  I read the FAQs specifically what type of questions should and should not be asked here and it seems to be in scope.

I am trying to learn LaTeX and maybe I am going the wrong way about it (by using Lyx) but I have a specific question that needs answering and if it cannot be (or won't be) answered here where do I go for answers.  Is this a Q&A site for experts only?  I am writing a book (see my profile) on a subject I am an expert on in a format I am not an expert on as there will be more books to follow so I am hoping to get to grips with it.  Is it the fact that I am "cutting my teeth" on Lyx rather than full blown LaTeX the reason for being too localized.  I would appreciate it if you can help me understand why my question will not be answered here.

Many thanks

Comment: It hasn't been closed as too localized because it's a LyX question, but (I think) because at the moment there's no way for others to reproduce the error. You should edit your question to include a minimal example and the exact error message you get, then it can be reopened (that's what Lionel and scottkosky tried to explain with their comments).

Answer (score 10):

In general, Lyx questions are within the scope of the site, although expertise in that area may be more limited than for 'straight' LaTeX questions.

While I did not vote to close the question linked, in the current form it does to me look 'too localized' because it doesn't contain enough detail to reproduce the issue (as Jake says in a comment). For example, without being able to see the Lyx source, LaTeX log, images or PDF there is a limit to what we can say (PDF files include images 'embeded', so this is not a general issue, for example). 'I got an error message' without the text of the error tends not to allow diagnosis.

As suggested by Jake, editing the question to include more info may well allow the question to be reopened. (My immediate thought is that you've got a DVI file rather than a PDF, as that would search for external files.)

Comment: My experience with LyX (about 2 years ago) is that there are errors occuring which do not occur while using `pdflatex` as a compiler. If you can compile your tex file with `pdflatex`, this would simplify the error finding in many cases (but it requires some knowledge about latex-code). Sometimes it is not even possible to open tex-files with LyX written with code editors. For improving your question you should give further details as explained above (log file and MWE if you can).

Answer (score 8):

This site is not only for experts, beginners are very welcome. However, it's a Q&A site, not a support forum, so try posting a good question which is of some value for the public.

You could improve your question for example by

- telling the error message (you just said that there is one)
- adding code which allows to test, to verify and to fix the problem

Closing is not final, once you improved the question we could reopen it.